# Getting the all rows of with any of the lastest N tags

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to get the all the records of the N latest Tags, i.e. ordered by timestamp.

I've managed to construct the following query that retrieves the latest 20 tags. However when I try to join on the result, the "limit" will affect the total number of rows, and not the number of unique tags.

```
SELECT id, tag, timestamp
FROM items AS T1 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM items AS T2
        WHERE T2.tag = T1.id AND T2.timestamp > T1.timestamp
    )
ORDER BY timestamp DESC 
LIMIT 20;
```

So given the following table...

```
 id | tag        | timestamp
----+------------+------------
  1 | Green      | 2019-04-30
  2 | Red        | 2019-04-29
  3 | Blue       | 2019-04-28
  4 | Green      | 2019-04-27
  5 | White      | 2019-04-26
  6 | Red        | 2019-04-25
  7 | Black      | 2019-04-24
  8 | Blue       | 2019-04-23
  9 | Red        | 2019-04-22
 10 | Black      | 2019-04-21
```

... A query for the lastest 3 latests tags should output the following or similar:

```
 id | tag        | timestamp
----+------------+------------
  1 | Green      | 2019-04-30
  4 | Green      | 2019-04-27
  2 | Red        | 2019-04-29
  6 | Red        | 2019-04-25
  9 | Red        | 2019-04-22
  3 | Blue       | 2019-04-28
  8 | Blue       | 2019-04-23
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the most recent 20, with duplicates:

```
SELECT id, tag, timestamp
FROM items i
WHERE i.tag IN (SELECT i2.tag
                FROM i2
                ORDER BY timestamp DESC
                FETCH FIRST 20 ROWS ONLY
               );
ORDER BY timestamp DESC ;
```

If you want the most recent 20 without duplicates:

```
SELECT id, tag, timestamp
FROM items i
WHERE i.tag IN (SELECT i2.tag
                FROM i2
                GROUP BY i2.tag
                ORDER BY MAX(timestamp) DESC
                FETCH FIRST 20 ROWS ONLY
               );
ORDER BY timestamp DESC
```